# Using CONCAT function in SQL for numbers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am getting introduced to SQL and lately I began to use the CONCAT function. I've seen its potential for joining some strings to others, especially when using text.

My question is: I tried the CONCAT function with numbers and i saw it works to put them together. But I don't know until what point this has potentialities for further data analysis. What I mean, how can CONCAT function be useful for data analytics by joining numbers?

I just tried to concatenate two numbers and it worked, but I didn't see any potential for data analysis.

Comment: It's for building text strings. While that's not to say there couldn't be value in some kind of analysis, it's probably more commonly used to generate human-readable output. It's a convenience that it will convert numeric types automatically.